# Loading screen with Synchronous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an Web app made with Ember.js and node.js that has an option to swtich between 3 languages. The words are stored in json files. As of now i am using synchronous ajax call to fetch the data for all the pages(around 7 or 8 calls).
The function

```js
function translate(iso,coll)
{
    var x = jQuery.parseJSON(
         jQuery.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin+'/translate?iso='+iso+'&coll='+coll,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
             success : function(){
             }
         }).responseText
    );
    console.log(x);
    return x;
};
```

My question is how can show an animated laoding screen until my calls are done.
Thank you.

Comment: You can't. It must be executed async for you to do that...

Comment: The problem is that i cant because all the views in Ember are dependant on the data from the json, if i put async true it throws an error

Comment: Then that is your actual problem which you need to post after producing a sort of [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Turning `async` off defeats the whole purpose of AJAX. If all the views in Ember are dependent on data fetched using AJAX, then initialize the views **after** all data has been successfully fetched, using the `.done()` deferred object/promise that is native to the `$.ajax()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Create an overlay section, hide it for the initial load. when you click the button and call the translate function show the overlay and hide it as an when it goes to success callback.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dvLoading" style="
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
">
  Loading
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function translate(iso,coll)
{
    $("#dvLoading").show();
    var x = jQuery.parseJSON(
         jQuery.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin+'/translate?iso='+iso+'&coll='+coll,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
             success : function(){
                $("#dvLoading").hide();
             }
         }).responseText
    );
    console.log(x);
    return x;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX**:

> Ajax (also AJAX; /ˈeɪdʒæks/; short for asynchronous JavaScript and
>   XML)[1](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)[3] is a group of interrelated Web development techniques
>   used on the client-side to create asynchronous Web applications. With
>   Ajax, web applications can send data to and retrieve from a server
>   asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the
>   display and behavior of the existing page. Data can be retrieved using
>   the XMLHttpRequest object. Despite the name, the use of XML is not
>   required (JSON is often used in the AJAJ variant), and the requests do
>   not need to be asynchronous.[4]

Taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

As you can see, AJAX is asynchronous by definition, therefore it is paradoxical and sub-optimal to make it synchronous. You need to modify your functionalities, so your request can run asynchronously and everything depending on it would be initialized/calculated in the `.done()` or the `success()`. Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).